# How to auto expand flex item to prevent item horizontal overflow?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container that contains some flex items. I would like the items to expand by default to contain all of their content without horizontally overflowing the flex container. As you can see from the attached image, "Content 7" is overflowing.

How the flex-container looks currently:

[image: How flexbox currently looks]

HTML:

```
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="flexItem">Content 4</div>
  <div class="flexItem">Content 5</div>
  <div class="flexItem">Content 6</div>
  <div class="flexItem">Content 7 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore vero deleniti veritatis iste at odit, quae placeat. Voluptas, dolorem dolore.</div>
  <div class="flexItem">Content 8</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 150px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

.flexItem {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Does that mean you don't want to wrap the text? What is the desired output?

Comment: what about the height in `flexContainer`  ?

Comment: @Sameer the desired output is to be able to set the height of the container to whatever I like and have the flex items accommodate for the height. A bit like how min-width:auto allows the size of the element to change based on the content, I want to expand on that and get the width to take into account the height of the flex container so that it doesn't overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `height: 150px` in `.flexContainer` to `height: fit-content` will do the job. Now the height of `.flexContainer` will expand until everything fits inside.

Change to the following code:

```
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 4px solid black;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: This is better than what I've got at the moment, and might be the best option there is, but its not what I'm looking for. I've added a comment to my question better explaining what I'm looking for.